# How do I tighten the screen hinge on my Macbook Pro (2010)?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a 2010 MBP and the screen has started to wobble - not un-usably, but just enough that when it is sitting on its stand the screen bobbles around a little when I type.

I took it back to a Genius at the Apple store and he said this was expected behaviour, and because it held its position, they weren't able to do anything about it. With that said, he was in a massive rush and running waaay behind - and I wanted to get a second opinion.

Should it sit still / can I ask them (within the 3-y Applecare I bought) to tighten it? Or is there anything I can do?

Comment: Could you please tell me what happened? I got MBP 13" 2012 and the screen wobbles a lot (about 2-3 cm) after 1 month of use. I wont be able to take it to a store for another month. What happened with yours?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling Apple Care, and or taking your MacBook Pro to a  [Apple Authorized Service Provider](http://solutionprofessionals.apple.com/aasp/), they may offer a much higher level of services satisfaction than a "really busy" Apple Retail Store in my experiences (East Cost, USA).

Comment: my experience in the UK is the exact reverse.  Genius Bar appointment over a Authorised Service Provider any day of the week.

Comment: Normally the Genius bar is very helpful where I am (Cardiff) but right now they seem to have cracked down on.. anything helpful / time consuming, which is a shame. There's an AASP around the corner though so I'll check in there and see what they say.